# generating a static highcharts json, but containing a function within

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, highcharts, flask

I have a flask server. One component of it generates json.

```
@app.route('/generate_json/some_chart')
def some_chart():
  ... # play around with data
  highcharts = {
    'title': {
      'text': 'example chart'
    },
    'xAxis': {
      'categories': [x['month'] for x in data]
    },
    'plotOptions': {
      'series': {
        'cursor': 'pointer',
        'events': {
          # here's where it is weird #
          'click': function() {
            $.getJSON(url_for('static', filename=some_chart.json), function(table_data) {
              make_table(table_data, this.category);
            })
          }
        }
      }
    },
    'series': [{
      'name': 'series one',
      'data': [x['series_one'] for x in data]
    }, {
      'name': 'series two',
      'data': [x['series_two'] for x in data]
    }]
  }
  return json.dumps(highcharts)
```

I do know that JSON does not allow for functions to be explicitly defined. What I am looking for, is perhaps some means of a work around.

This might mean putting some existing 'marker' and the javascript figuring out how to interpret it

Comment: this may provide you with some ideas: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3338397/changing-string-to-a-function-in-javascript-not-eval

Comment: In general functions are not avaible in json, so it is not related with the highchart.

Comment: ah adrichman that was very helpful, thank you